# How to create a Git tag only for a specific branch?

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Probably a very basic question. But i could not be sure even after reading through multiple resources.

> In SVN, I used to create a tag called **dev_tag** from the branch called
>   **dev_branch**.  I also have a requirement to checkout the dev_tag into
>   checkout_dir and do a maven build.

**SVN**  - *This is what i did earlier*

```
 ~ -> svn copy -m  svn+ssh://<repo>/branches/dev_branch/ svn+ssh://<repo>/tags/dev_tag/ 
 ~ -> svn co svn+ssh://<repo>/tags/dev_tag/ checkout_dir
 ~ -> cd checkout_dir
 ~/checkour_dir -> mvn clean package
```

**GIT** - *How to ?*

> How to do the above in Git? This is how my git looks now.

```
 ~ -> git branch -l
  dev_branch
* master
```

**Re-phrasing:**
Agreed, w.r.t just creating a tag. My question was more in-terms of

> "Suppose, if i had the git repo contain the master branch(for prod
>   deployment) and dev branch(for QA deployment) each having different
>   changes. Next, I create a tag by typing 'git tag mytag' with current
>   branch as master. Now to QA , i would need to give commands which will
>   only checkout the dev branch content on which they can do mvn build.
>   With the same tag, I should be able to checkout the master branch
>   content which can be built and used for prod deployment."

Finally this is what i did to create Git tags for specific branches and tar for the same
which helps me build qa and prod code separately.

**QA_BUILD**

```
git clone -b dev_branch gitserve:repo.git qa
cd qa
tag -a qa_tag
git commit -a
git push --tags
git archive --format=tar --remote=gitserve:repo.git tags/qa_tag > /tmp/qabuild/qa.tar
cd  /tmp/qabuild
tar -xvf qa.tar
mvn clean package
```

**PROD_BUILD**

```
git clone -b master gitserve:repo.git prod
cd prod
tag -a prod_tag
git commit -a
git push --tags
git archive --format=tar --remote=gitserve:repo.git tags/prod_tag > /tmp/prodbuild/prod.tar
cd  /tmp/prodbuild
tar -xvf prod.tar
mvn clean package
```

Comment: Maybe I'm still not understanding what you're looking for - the way I'm reading your re-phrasing, it sounds like you want a single tag to check out two separate branches? If that's the case, I don't think that's possible, unless you ignore branches altogether and just keep dev and prod in two separate directories, which would be considerably less than ideal, I think. A tag points to a single commit, which is in one specific spot in the history graph. That could end up being on multiple branches, depending on merges, though.

Comment: I added the commands at the bottom of my post. I think this will make it clear

Answer (score 6):

Tags in `git` are different than what they are in `svn`. They're essentially equivalent to fixed branches (i.e. once created they don't move as further commits are made) - just a pointer to a simple commit. So, to create a tag, you do one of two things - if you already have the commit you want to tag checked out, you can drop a tag where you are with:

```
git tag <tagname>
```

If you aren't at the commit you want to tag, you'll need to use `git log` or some other method to find the SHA hash of the commit you want, then you can run:

```
git tag <tagname> <sha>
```

(Alternatively you can `git checkout <sha>; git tag <tagname>`, but that's an unnecessary checkout, and can cause confusion if you forget to re-checkout to where you want to be for future development work.

Comment: Agreed, w.r.t just creating a tag. My question was more in-terms of  "Suppose, if i had the git repo contain the master branch(for prod deployment) and dev branch(for QA deployment) each having different changes. Next, I create a tag by typing 'git tag mytag' with current branch as master. Now to QA , i would need to give commands which will only checkout the dev branch content on which they can do mvn build. With the same tag, I should be able to checkout the master branch content which can be built and used for prod deployment."

Answer (score 4):

**You can't.**

A `tag` is points a `<commit-id>`. tags exist independently of branches.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to tag the latest release `latest` (etc.) and then delete and re-create it each time you have a release.

HOWEVER this is not the normal way tags are used, which is as fixed locations, but as long as all the team understands which tags are fixed, and and which tags float around you should be OK.

Comment: that's a really strange way to use tags, `latest` should be a branch tip of a stable branch as in http://nvie.com/git-model

Comment: @CharlesB, people can be strange. Some find a tag (possibly even signed) more suitable. I'd guess they would be concerned that folk could give their local stable branch a different name and get confused. There's no accounting for taste.

Comment: I don't find good advice to mimic legacy behaviours... just my opinion, though

Comment: @CharlesB, I accept that. Git (DVCS) is different to the legacy approaches.